# BeautifulSoup. Search optimization for one link

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I get a link from an HTML page to a PDF document -

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'doc'}, href=True):
    pdfLink = a['href']
```

If I know for sure that there is only one link. Is it possible to do with one line of code?

Something like -

```
pdfLink = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'doc'}, href=True) + additional keys
```

P.S. I do not need the whole tag, I only need the content of "href".

Source from HTML:

```
<a href="https://company.co/doc-specification/08de9a7c037e67e56dc847c7fb08e0a6/Specification.pdf" target="_blank" class="doc" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'GTMevent', 'eventLabel': 'Specification PDF', 'eventAction': 'Product Page', 'eventCategory': 'Internal Link'});" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title="Specification PDF">
```

Source from SOUP:

```
<a class="doc" data-original-title="Specification PDF" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://company.co/doc-specification/08de9a7c037e67e56dc847c7fb08e0a6/Specification.pdf" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'GTMevent', 'eventLabel': 'Specification PDF', 'eventAction': 'Product Page', 'eventCategory': 'Internal Link'});" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Hi,May I know why you haven't accepted or voted any of the answers you have got in all your previous question?

Comment: Hello.
Sorry, I'm new here. I clicked the up arrow on all answers, but they wrote that I do not have rights yet and my vote is counted but not displayed.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'll try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **CSS** selector `select_one`() which will find the 1st occurrence.

> soup.select_one('a.doc[href]') will identify anchor tag whose class name is doc and having href attribute.

So get the href value

```
pdfLink = soup.select_one('a.doc[href]')['href']
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but got the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Added to first post. In the HTML code and in the Soup, the links look different.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is only one link on the page, then using `soup.find('a', {'class':'doc'}, href=True)` should work: no `for` required.

This will find the first instance of a link with the doc class.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t need the whole tag, I only need the contents of "href".

Comment: Using Kunduk's method, you can use this `doc_link = soup.find('a', {'class':'doc'})['href']`. Print the `doc_link` and it should work.

Comment: I tried for a long time to use this method, but still did not get the result.
I added the full HTML fragment to the first message, can you try it yourself does Kunduk's method work for you?

Comment: using `doc_link = soup.find('a', {'class':'doc'})['href']`, I was able to get this to print: `https://company.co/doc-specification/08de9a7c037e67e56dc847c7fb08e0a6/Specification.pdf`